# How to Input a Number that changes Total

Tags: javascript, html, cart, commerce

The input field does not register 
(discount is supposed to subtract from Grand Total)

### Check the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Drsxg?editors=101)

#### Javascript

```
function recordToFilename() {
  var input = document.getElementById('discountvalue'),
  discount12 = input.value;
}
```

I want it to act like this picture below. (with the discount being manually inputed)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV8QT.jpg

Comment: please try to code cleaner. I can't make anything out of this. js is between html and its all unordered. seperate the js from html and css

Comment: you have made it hard for yourself to adjust the grand total, because you have also inserted html elements along with the value try to separate these

Comment: Take a look at it here thanks [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKdnL?editors=101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get value of they discount because it also include text.

```
JS = document.getElementById('discountsample').innerHTML = " Discount Sample: $" + (-10).toFixed(2);
HTML Output = <h4 id="discountsample"> Discount Sample: $-10.00</h4>
```

Add the value in a attribute like price so the output will be like

```
<h4 id="discountsample" price="10.00"> Discount Sample: $-10.00</h4>
```

You can read the value from the price. 
In your last JS you set it in that and also this way you can get the value and substract it.

```
  function recordToFilename() 
  {
      var input = document.getElementById('discountvalue'),

      //Something like this. This requires jQuery
      document.getElementById('discountsample').attr("price", input.value);

      //I don't know how it is in normal JS. I think its like this but you have to test it
      document.getElementById('discountsample').attributes['id'] = input.value;
  };
```

And also make the code cleaner like detaching the JS from the HTML and vice versa. 
Now it's just all mixed up. Some in your HTML and some in your JS

Comment: yes thank you , the javascript and html cannot be detached because I am using a program where I only get one page to write my code. It is running offline so I cannot use jQuery.

Comment: I am trying the .attributes[id] thanks

Comment: yeah good. let me know if it works and if this is the solution you are looking for :)